# Simple bash scripting with echo, sed, and variables

Tags: bash, list, sed, echo

I'm having this problem:
I want to use the sed command to replace a line in a file,

```
sudo sed -i 's/option=setting A/option=setting B/g' ~configfile
```

This line should be part of a .sh file, so I added "> myscript.sh" (which is represented by variables below). I also have several possible options variables that are listed in a list:

> options.list

Which contains

> A
>
> B
>
> C

So, I want to search and replace a variable, no matter what it was, to the new value within the list. That's why I used `option=.*$` in the first part of sed. The second part of the sed should combine the chain `"setting= "` with all the options from options.list. All that have to be pushed in a .sh file.

So, to combine the whole stuff I tried this:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
     echo "#!/bin/bash" >> "$_dest""$file".sh
     echo sed -i 's/option=.*$/option="setting ""$file"/g' ~configfile >> "$_dest""$file".sh        
done < "$options.list"
```

But there is a problem with echo and sed, probably related with backslashes or something... I tried hard but still with no solution. SOrry I know this is probably a silly question :)

Answer (score 0):

First, have you any error message?

You could try something like :

```
sed -i 's/\(option=\).*$/\1"setting '$file'"/g' ~configfile
```

I don't understand why you use `echo` before your sed. If you want to print the output of sed in the standard output (stdout), you could use sed without `-i` option. Be ware, `-i`option directly make the replacement into the input file.

Otherwise, is `~configfile` the real name of your file ? If you want to use `~` like your own directory (`/home/your_name`), use it like this :

```
~/configfile
```